# How can I tell if a user bought my app

Tags: android, google-play

I sell a game on Google Play called [Quantum-X](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adamlock.qix). Not many people have bought it so I want to move to an ad-supported model and make it a free download.

But I want to reward the people who did buy the game by disabling advertising. So existing users see no ads, new users see ads. I can store a flag in some obfuscated, device specific way which makes this determination.

But in order to this I need to tell the difference between paying and non paying users.

So how do I do this? I have a few ideas but I don't know if any of them are viable:

1. The old app wrote some preferences out. I could look for an old preference and set the flag. But this will not work if someone installs the app on a clean device since they won't have that preference. It is also an exploit since anybody could put the old key in to fool my app into disabling advertising.
2. My pay app currently uses LVL to validate a person's licence. If I make my app free, what happens when I call LVL? Does it respond LICENCED even if a user downloaded it for nothing? If I could tell paid from non-paying users from the response then I know how to set the flag. But LVL is a pain to test since I would have to upload the app, set it to free and then see what difference there is in the result and there may be none.
3. I could produce one final update of my pay app which sets the flag and asks users to upgrade. Then I could roll out the app free in a month from now. The same problem exists as with 1. that some users may not update or may install onto clean devices.
4. I could produce two apps on the store. The pay app could be renamed to "Quantum-X legacy" and a new Quantum-X goes in its place which is free. I would update the legacy version to install the flag, but people would have to switch to the new version for continued support. This would work but it's a lot more effort.

None of these are pretty although 2. would be the least amount of work. Has anyone experience of a working solution, or know a some better way of doing this?

EDIT: My intention is now a hybrid and I've begun to do this:

1. Rename the old app as Quantum-X Legacy and update the description.
2. The new free version is called Quantum-X. The only fly in the ointment here is that I must update the app package in the manifest to make the two apps distinct.
3. I intend to put a test into the free version that calls LVL using the old app's key. If this works the way I think it will, it will tell me when a user has bought the old app (since the licence server is being asked about the old app), and I can write out an obfuscated flag somewhere so I don't have to call LVL any more.
4. Free users carry on but with ads.

I'm up to 3. and this is my intention. If LVL doesn't work, then I might have to put out an update to the legacy version which writes the flag or puts a code out on screen that someone must use to enable adfree when they install the other version.

Comment: I would recommend that you go with 2 apps, one payed and one free. What i know from experience is that you shouldn't rely on old preferences files :( . Also what i would recommend for future projects is that you always implement a version checker with your server for ex., and promt users to update if its critical or at least notice them in such cases...otherwise they dont have to be aware of the process.

Comment: I think I'm going to do a hybrid. I've created two versions of the app (a slight pain since I have to change the app package and will have to move people over). Phase 2 will either to be use LVL from the new app with the old app's key to disable ads, or produce a new version of the old app that writes out a key. I think the former is better than the latter.

Comment: LVL didn't work in the end. You can't call LVL from one package even if you supply the package and key of another package since it returns with a uid error.